# About database workload characters and prediction

Tags: database, prediction, workload

everyone. Recently I have read some papers about database tuning for my own research. However, I am a little confused about such words like "dynamic workload", "changing workload", "workload characteristics".

In my comprehension, a database workload is a set of queries like "scan", "read", "insert", "update" or "delete". But how can we describe that a database workload has 'changed'?

For example, if my DBMS is about to run for an hour, dealing with a lot of queries (maybe using benchmark like YCSB). Then in the first ten minutes, my read/write operation is fifty-to-fifty, in the next ten minutes, all queries are read operations. Can I consider it a change of workload?

By the way, how can I exactly describe the characteristics of a specific workload? Its executing time, transaction throughput or anything else?
By obtaining these characteristics (parameters), I can use a prediction model to forecast what kind of workload will come in the future, thus promote system performance.

I have read some materials in website https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB/wiki/Running-a-Workload but that does not answer my questions yet.

I think this problem is very important for everyone who works in database area, and can you kindly offer me some guide about this?

Comment: Your questions seem to suggest that you have a pretty good understanding of the subject.  Normally, the term "workload" would be used in a tuning context.  Changes over a 10-minute span are probably too short a span.  You might be more interested in understanding the different ways that a specific database can be tuned, to optimize reads versus writes, for instance.

Comment: But at this moment I have to learn and design some strategies for parameter tuning in database that can serve in a wide area, but not only for a specified database. That's why I care about the definition of 'workload', which is something to be describe in mathematical form. Anyway, thanks for your reply.